# Saving multiple Json object in single file

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, web-scraping, github-api

I am trying to parse github api for organisations for this link
 [first link](https://api.github.com/orgs/mozilla/repos)
I collected all commit_url from this link and then I need to save data from each commit link for further cleaning.

e.g I have two commit links as
[commit_link1](https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/tuxedo/commits) and [commit_link2](https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/zamboni/commits)

As data in both links is again JSON object I tried saving data in JSON file with apend mode but when I open the file to get data I got keyerror: extra data

Any idea how should I save the data in single file as CSV option don't look reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top level item in a JSON file must be a single value, for example a single object (a `dict` in Python) or a single list. Therefore, you cannot simply append two JSON objects in a single file.

You can either collect all these objects in a list and then store that list instead, or you can use the [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) file format, which consists of multiple JSON values (e.g. objects), separated by newlines. Note however, that "standard" JSON tools won't know how to deal with JSON Lines. For Python, you can use the [`jsonlines`](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

Comment: what if that Json object is an array? how to deal in this case?

Comment: Depends on your use case: you can either merge the two arrays and store the resulting (single) array, you can nest them in a list and store that list, or you can use JSON lines.

Comment: can you please give me an example of above case that I mention? thanks

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: this one "merge the two arrays and store the resulting (single) array"

Comment: Keep a list (say `results = []`) and as you load a new list from each JSON file (say `file_results = json.load(f)`) you add it to your total list (`results.extend(file_results)`). When you're done you store the total list (`json.dump(results, f)`).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this old question:
JSON-lines is a good way to go. Its json, but each line is a json (i.e. json are separated by '\n')

Saving:

(*.jsonl is typical file extension for json lines)

```py
import json

file_name = "data.jsonl"  # your desired file name  
list_objs = []  # the list of objects you want to save as json

# convert object to strings
text = "\n".join([json.dumps(json_) for json_ in list_objs])

# save
with open(file_name, "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Loading:

```py
import json

file_path = "#####.jsonl"  # your file path

data = []
with open(file_path, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```